# Select rows with a partial string match of two columns in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset similar to the following:

```
data<- tibble('year' = c(1850,1860,1870), 'TallestPerson' = c('Abe Lincoln', 'Abe 
Lincoln', 'Paul Bunyon'), 'President'=c('Taylor', 'Lincoln', 'Grant'))
```

In table form:

```
    year  TallestPerson  President
1   1850  Abe Lincoln    Taylor
2   1860  Abe Lincoln    Lincoln
3   1870  Paul Bunyon    Grant
```

I'm looking for a way to select the second row of this table due to the the President's name being part of the tallest person's name.

I have attempted

```
tall_presidents <- data %>% filter(data$President %in% data$TallestPerson)
```

This returns an empty tibble, due to (I assume) the TallestPerson and President not matching exactly. How can I select the rows where the presidents name is contained in the tallest person's name?

If this were SQL, the statement I am looking for would be

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE TallestPerson LIKE "%"+President+"%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   filter(str_detect(TallestPerson, President))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#    year TallestPerson President 
#  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>    
#1  1860 Abe Lincoln   Lincoln
```

NOTE: Within the `tidyverse` functions, we don't need to specify the `data$` to get the value of the column.

Comment: This works in my sample data. Thank you. However, when I implement into my real dataset I recieve this error:  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: @ckett  You can convert both columns to character and then apply the `str_detect` i.e. `data %>% mutate_at(vars(TallestPerson, President), as.character) %>% filter(..`